# How to create a user defined function such as ISNULL? Parameter is Expression and return type is the type of replace type

Tags: sql-server

How can I create a user defined function that behaves in a similar manner to the builtin [`ISNULL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) in SQLServer2017?

> ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )
>
> Arguments
>
> check_expression Is the expression to be checked for NULL.
>   **check_expression can be of any type**.
>
> Return Types **Returns the same type as check_expression.**

How can I create my own functions with this behaviour?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you do you want to do. Please elaborate with some example

Comment: You can refer to following on how to create `User-Defined Functions` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you want to do - and this isn't possible.

You can't create a single user defined function `dbo.Foo` that returns an `int` when passed an `int` and a `varchar` when passed a `varchar` for example.

You can use `sql_variant` as the type of the input parameter and the return type but this isn't really the same.